# how to fire a salesforce trigger only if we update a custom field

Tags: triggers, salesforce, field, updates

Is there way to create trigger on `salesforce custom object` that will be fired only if we update one custom field and not every time we update the whole object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General, the triggers are fired whenever there is a change to any/all fields in the object. What you can do is compare the value in trigger.old with the value in trigger.new

eg:

```
trigger TestTrigger on Account (before update) {
  for(Account a : Trigger.new){
            if(a.Active__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(a.id).Active__c)
                System.debug('change in Active field');


        }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i already asked in other forums and they answer me the same